# ASP.net solution considerations for multi server deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net, deployment, cloud, load-balancing

I've done all my development of an ASP.net website under the assumption that it will be deployed to a single server.  Since we're expanding we're looking at hosting scalably in the cloud with multiple VM's running the website.  We are taking expert advise on deployment, but the hired help we have are expecting an ASP.net site that will work in a load balanced environment.

I'm researching what in my solution may need to change for it to work on a multi server deployment.

So far, I've found that all my caching needs to be done on a distributed cache such as NCache.  The code changes required for this don't look too bad.

We don't use sessions for user authentication, it's all done via cookies so I don't think that will cause any issues.

What other general considerations need to be made?  (I've looked for a guide but can't find one).

Comment: if you use sessions to store data between calls, you are going to need to move to the SqlServerSessionProvider. 
you'll also need to have the same machine key for all servers on the load balancer or viewstate won't work.

Comment: You wish to go for web Farm but my question is : on one computer do you have all ready use web garden ?

Comment: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/LoadBalancingAndASPNET.aspx

Comment: @Fran thanks for link, brilliant!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use sessions to store data between calls, you are going to need to move to the SqlServerSessionProvider. you'll also need to have the same machine key for all servers on the load balancer or viewstate won't work.

Here's a [link](http://hanselman.com/blog/LoadBalancingAndASPNET.aspx) from Scott Hanselman that list the gotchas.